# How to save a picture in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, save, image

Goal:
Save a picture from the harddrive into my WPF application. The picture should be available if copying the WPF application. The address to the picture located in the WPF application should be saved in the database.

Problem:
How should I do it in a course of action?

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

    dlg.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|gif files (*.gif)|*.gif|jpeg files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg";

    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    if (result == true)
    {
        // Open document
        string filename = dlg.FileName;

        txtPicture.Text = filename;

        BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(dlg.FileName, UriKind.Absolute));
        string sss = myBitmapImage.Format.ToString();
        string asd = dlg.SafeFileName.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several [image encoders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608877%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) available. A simple example for PNG files can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.pngbitmapencoder%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), or a more complete sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771771%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). The same concept applies for the other supported image file types.

Comment: Do you know how to save a picture inside of a WPF application?

Comment: @FullmetalBoy - Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. The links above are for WPF applications.

Comment: Another problem I'm facing is to save a picture from the harddrive into my WPF application without saving pictures in the database. The way you add an existing picture in your VS 2010 and the picture will be saved inside of a project/library. It is the same concept but you create an WPF application and store pictures inside of WPF application. Please tell me if you need more explaination.

Comment: @FullmetalBoy - It's probably best to focus on the first issue before asking additional questions. I still don't understand the question in your first comment. Unfortunately, you second question is just as confusing.